# Division of large numbers in Small Number in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly

I Am New In Assembly Language and i got one problem in Division.When i Enter 4 Digit Input then on Displaying/Output program Show me Input Value in Reverse Order.

For Example:

if i enter "1234" then Program output is "4321" but i want "1234" output.

please tell me if any one know about this.and see the code

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
arr dw 0,0
ten db 10

.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,48
mov al,al
mul ten
mov arr,ax

mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,48
mov ah,0
add arr,ax
mov ax,arr
mov al,al
mul ten
mov arr,ax

mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,48
mov ah,0
add arr,ax
mov ax,arr
mov al,al
mul ten
mov arr,ax

mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,48
mov ah,0
add arr,ax

;Strat Division from Here

mov ax,arr
div ten
mov ch,ah
mov cl,al
mov ah,2
mov dl,ch
add dl,48
int 21h
mov ah,0
mov al,cl
div ten

mov ch,ah
mov cl,al
mov ah,2
mov dl,ch
add dl,48
int 21h
mov ah,0
mov al,cl
div ten
mov ch,ah
mov cl,al
mov ah,2
mov dl,ch
add dl,48
int 21h

mov dl,cl
add dl,48
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```